# How to find largest count using table in a matrix in R

Tags: r

Suppose I had the following matrix

```
    m = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), ncol = 3)
    > m
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    0    1
    [2,]    0    0    1
    [3,]    0    0    0
```

I want to have a count of the values for each of the columns, so

```
    table(m[,1])
    table(m[,2])
    table(m[,3])
```

And I want to figure out what's the value (either 0, or 1) that has the largest counts (appears more than the other). So for column 1 I would want R to return 0 (because there are more 0's than 1's), for column 2, R should return 0, and for column 3 return 1.

I've tried which.max() but that only gives me the index. Not the value with the largest count.

Comment: Yes but how can I find the value with the largest number of counts in each of those tables?

Comment: `lapply(lapply(split(m, col(m)), table), function(x) names(which.max(x)))` or `apply(m,2,function(x) names(which.max(table(x))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with a binary matrix, you can use `colMeans`

```
as.numeric(colMeans(m) > 0.5)
# [1] 0 0 1
```

since `colMeans(m)` gives you the percentage of 1's in each column

Comment: `colMeans` is equivalent to the first part of this answer.

Comment: Ah yes!  I always forget that function exists

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use indexation and which.max, as you had proposed. To make things simpler, it can be done using apply and a function indexing which.max Thus, following your example matrix:

```
apply(m,2,function (X) as.numeric(names(table(X)[which.max(table(X))])))
```